# I have a co routine that once selected plays through. However If i go to select it again nothing happens. It does work the first time however

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, co, routines

I have a co routine that once selected plays through. The co routine scales an object up. The second one it's selected it scales down the object.

However If i go to select it again nothing happens. It does work the first time however.

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class square : MonoBehaviour
{

    public Transform Button;
    float ElapsedTime = 0.0f;
    float TotalTime = 0.4f;

    private bool _isenlargingcanvas;

    public void enlargecanvas()
    {
        if (_isenlargingcanvas)
            return;
        _isenlargingcanvas = true;
        StartCoroutine(transitionscale());
        _isenlargingcanvas = false;
    }

    IEnumerator transitionscale()

    {

        while (ElapsedTime < TotalTime)
        {
            ElapsedTime += Time.deltaTime;
            Button.localScale = Vector3.Lerp(new Vector3(0, 0, 0), new
            Vector3(9, 7, 7), (ElapsedTime / TotalTime));
            yield return null;
        }
    }

    private bool _isshrinkingcanvas;

    public void shrinkcanvas()
    {
        if (_isshrinkingcanvas)
            return;
        _isshrinkingcanvas = true;
        StartCoroutine(transitionscaledown());
        _isshrinkingcanvas = false;
    }

    IEnumerator transitionscaledown()

    {

        while (ElapsedTime < TotalTime)
        {
            ElapsedTime += Time.deltaTime;
            Button.localScale = Vector3.Lerp(new Vector3(9, 7, 7), new
            Vector3(0, 0, 0), (ElapsedTime / TotalTime));
            yield return null;
        }
    }

}
```

I have a co routine that once selected plays through. The co routine scales an object up. The second one it's selected it scales down the object.

However If i go to select it again nothing happens. It does work the first time however.

Comment: So add some debug statements - the fact your _isshrink is set to false again possibly before the coroutine ever really starts, wont help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks to me like you're not resetting the `ElapsedTime` field so if you were to re-enter the `transitionscale()` method the condition in the `while` statement is already false so the method exits without doing anything.

Possible solutions to this are, the reset the variable before calling the method each time... as follows

```
// Inside the elarge canvas method
ElapsedTime = 0.0f;
StartCoroutine(transitionscale());
```

Alternatviely, and with less work, you can reset it inside the tranisition scale method.

```
IEnumerator transitionscale()

{
    ElapsedTime = 0.0f;

    while (ElapsedTime < TotalTime)
    {
        ElapsedTime += Time.deltaTime;
        Button.localScale = Vector3.Lerp(new Vector3(0, 0, 0), new
        Vector3(9, 7, 7), (ElapsedTime / TotalTime));
        yield return null;
    }
}
```

You'll need to do the same for the `trasitionscaledown()` method. Consider one of those changes and see if that solves your problem.